# Map two dataframes with different number of rows based on year month and day of their columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like to following (df1):

```
index,col1,col2
2020-01-01,A,Y
2020-01-02,B,Z
```

And another like the following (df2):

```
index,date, .....
1,2020-01-01 13:44
2,2020-01-01 15:22
3,2020-01-01 23:11
4,2020-01-01 13:44
5,2020-01-02 13:28
6,2020-01-02 17:55
```

I need to map df2['date'] year, month and day with df1.index year, month and day to get a final dataframe like the following:

```
index,col1,col2
2020-01-01 13:44,A,Y
2020-01-01 15:22,A,Y
2020-01-01 23:11,A,Y
2020-01-01 13:44,A,Y
2020-01-02 13:28,B,Z
2020-01-02 17:55,B,Z
```

Something like the following would do the work:

```
pd.Dataframe(mapped_values, index=df2['date'], columns=df1.columns)
```

How can I get mapped_values here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try merge:

```
df2['day'] = df2['date'].dt.normalize()
df2.merge(df1, left_on='day', right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
                     date        day col1 col2
index                                         
1     2020-01-01 13:44:00 2020-01-01    A    Y
2     2020-01-01 15:22:00 2020-01-01    A    Y
3     2020-01-01 23:11:00 2020-01-01    A    Y
4     2020-01-01 13:44:00 2020-01-01    A    Y
5     2020-01-02 13:28:00 2020-01-02    B    Z
6     2020-01-02 17:55:00 2020-01-02    B    Z
```

Answer (score 0):

The following does it.

Modules

```
import pandas as pd
import io
```

Data

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
index,col1,col2
2020-01-01,A,Y
2020-01-02,B,Z
"""), sep=",", engine="python")

df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
index,date
1,2020-01-01 13:44
2,2020-01-01 15:22
3,2020-01-01 23:11
4,2020-01-01 13:44
5,2020-01-02 13:28
6,2020-01-02 17:55
"""), sep=",", engine="python")
```

Date formatting

```
df1['ndate'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['index'])
df2['ndate'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])
df2['ndate'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['ndate'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Merge

```
pd.merge(df2, df1, on=['ndate'])
```